# Calculating LAT/LON GPS location movement

Tags: geolocation, gps, calculation

I'm using Ublox M9N GPS modules, outputting NMEA sentences: $GNRMC,162254.00,A,3723.02837,N,11150.39853,W,0.820,188.36,110706,,,A*74

I'm no mathematician, but need to calculate movement in my project.

My system uses joysticks to increment LAT and LON, so 1x increment LAT (STEP) would be:
3723.0283**7**
3723.0283**8**

Using both LAT and LON would give an angle from the start location, and after calculation, would give a new location.

How is this done please?

Ask any question to make sure all is understood.
Thanks,Camerart.

I haven't tried anything yet, as I don't know how to start.

I have difficulty using radio controlled models, due to my eyesight, so am trying another way to 'drive' them.  They could be planes, boats, or cars.

Comment: It is simple trigonometry. Look Wikipedia: so you will find exactly the formula you need, and possibly all related formula you will for sure use, when you start programming. Note: if you displacements are not near the poles, and not large (so within tens of km), you can use lat long as y,x Cartesian coordinates, so simple trigonometry. NOTE: your latitude is not a latitude angle, right? is it 37 degree 23 primes? or what? You should understand your units. (and again Wikipedia "degree of latitude" will help you on estimate errors using cartesian geometry)

Comment: a couple of links: https://gpsd.gitlab.io/gpsd/NMEA.html has a good description of common NMEA sentences, and https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html describes how to use trig for a few common tasks

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your reply.  For me it's not so simple, as it's right out of my sphere.  I've also has replies from other forums, which are similar to yours, and don't really help me pick out the ends of my spaghetti thoughts, when it comes to trigonometry, and other maths.  Cheers, Camerart.

Comment: I'd suggest talking to a friend who could help explain what's going on, or maybe google for applied trig courses.  as you're asking on a programming website, you could also try stepping through the maths from the links I gave in a REPL (e.g. Python) and plotting results to help make sense of what's going on.  that's something I'd do when I come across something I don't understand

Comment: Hi S, Thanks.  I think I've figured out how to do it without trigonometry, by using more or less for calculations.  I'm working though it. C